# Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed to retrieve auth metadata with error: Could not refresh access token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

The complete error is as follows:

```
Unhandled error Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed to retrieve auth metadata with error: Could not refresh access token: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 500
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:327:49)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Caused by: Error
at Query._get (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1449:23)
at Query.get (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1438:21)
at Object.getTeacherDataWithFilters (/workspace/lib/teachers/methods.js:168:81)
at /workspace/lib/teachers/callable.js:22:36
at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:273:32)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
code: 16,
details: 'Failed to retrieve auth metadata with error: Could not refresh access token: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 500',
metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
```

I recently deployed to the firebase functions and now I am getting this error. I dont know what has happened and I could not find anything specific to this

Comment: Could you share the code that is causing this error?

Comment: I have resolved the issue and it was because of the default service account being disabled. :P

Comment: Answering this in case someone stumbles upon this answer.

Although this error makes it seem as though no token was sent, it can be triggered by a bad token.
If you're generating Google tokens yourself, check the basic jwt claims (`exp`, `iat`, `nbf`...) to make sure they are valid.

Also, check the time in your system to ensure there's no drift causing the token to be invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figured out the actual reason and that's why I am answering my own question. The reason why I was getting this error is that the default service account attached to this project which is mostly like `<project-ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` was **disabled**. After enabling, everything worked fine.

Comment: It worked for me. 
You can add your answer to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754230/how-do-i-update-firestore-db-using-from-cloud-functions-authentication-issues

Please include pictures or instructions on how to get to Service Accounts.

Comment: It worked for me too, thank you, u saved my time! But in my case, this service was disabled in another project what was generated based on firebase, and didn't base on the play market console.

Comment: you enabled it from firebase right? I am able to run everything locally but not when deployed

Comment: @ShivamSahil it has to be done from https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts page

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same error, it was a authentication issue due to credentials. Below command fixed it for me.

```
 gcloud auth application-default login
```

I got below output after running this command.

> Credentials saved to file: [/Users/username/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]. These credentials will be used by any library that requests Application Default Credentials (ADC).

[Official Document for Reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)

Comment: this worked for me, can you link to some official documentation that adress this solution for future reference.

Comment: @eguneys i have added the document link. Glad that it worked for you.

Comment: We were also seeing a similar error with reason "invalid_grant" - this command fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try saving .env file in UTF-8
2. What worked for me: process.env.TOKEN.replace(/\n/gm, '\n')

Answer (score 3):

In case someone deploying on Vercel, there's a minor change you need to do when setting PRIVATE_KEY env variable. You need to remove starting and ending double quote from key. Save it like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgk
.
.
.
4xxjFxhpK5GLYmGSZzpv5Y=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Comment: Hmm I am deploying it in vercel but this isn't working... can you tell a bit more about the configuration? Do you scrap "\n" in the initializeApp too?

Answer (score 0):

In case it's working fine in your local environment but somehow failing in any production build, here's a nice hack to get it sorted in any platform:

Also, this works like a charm in Vercel (Note that while adding environment variables in Vercel you must not put any quotations and paste it directly like:
`{"privateKey":"XXX...."}`

```
//.env.local File:
FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY='{"privateKey":"XXX...."}'
```

And your configuration:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

const keyString = process.env.FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY ?? '{"privateKey": ""}'; //Since it's a TypeScript so need to ensure that I pass a valid string to the JSON.parse as FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY can be undefined

const { privateKey } = JSON.parse(keyString);

if (privateKey === '') {
  //In case you want to confirm things in Server Logs
  console.log('FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY is not set');
}

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    clientEmail: process.env.FB_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: privateKey,
    projectId: process.env.FB_ADMIN_PROJECT_ID,
  }),
});

const db = admin.firestore();
const auth = admin.auth();

export { auth, db };
```

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario is if you have a deployed app engine app that uses google apis, then in gcp you delete and recreate the (custom or default) service account (maybe with terraform for example).

It won't authenticate until you redeploy the app.